# How to make a project where I'm a collaborator invisible on my Github?

Tags: git, github

There is a project on Github where I'm a collaborator, and I want to make it invisible to people who visit my Github page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GitHub page reflects the project visibility.

You would need to ask the project maintainer to change the [project visibility to private](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#private-projects)